# Cannot export the ORDDataSource object with an external source

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying create a procedure like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE export_dicom (identyfikator_wyniku number, new_file_name varchar2)
AS 
    obr ORDDicom;
BEGIN
    SELECT dicom_zrodlo INTO obr FROM wyniki WHERE  id_wyniku = identyfikator_wyniku;
    obr.export('FILE', 'MEDIA_FILES', new_file_name);
END;
```

But when I create it and use it, I get an error like this:

```
ORA-53216: cannot export the ORDDataSource object with an external source
ORA-06512: at "ORDSYS.ORDERROR", line 5
ORA-06512: at "ORDSYS.ORDDATASOURCE", line 265
ORA-06512: at "ORDSYS.ORDDICOM", line 234
ORA-06512: at "ZAD2.export_dicom", line 6
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: are you using obr as a variable name and a schema name?

Comment: "obr" is a variable only. "obr ORDDicom;"

Comment: obr ORDDicom; is a variable of type what? should it be obr ORDDicom%type?

Comment: ORDDicom is a type.  Am I wrong ? 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28416/ch_dev_ref.htm#CHDHJHAD